# equalsStringSensitive built-in filter function not recognized by React Table v8.8.4

Tags: react-table, react-table-v8

I'm using react-table v8.8.4 with the filtering functionality enabled like this:

```
const table = useReactTable({
        columns,
        data,
        enableColumnFilters: true,
        enableFilters: true,
        getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
        getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),            
        state: {
            columnFilters,
            columnVisibility,
            globalFilter,
            sorting               
        },
        enableGlobalFilter: true,
        globalFilterFn: 'includesString',
        onSortingChange: setSorting,    
        enableSorting: true,
        enableSortingRemoval: false,     

});
```

At `state.columnFilters` I'm passing an array with the following structure:

```
[{
    id: 'Severity',
    value: ...
}]
```

The column is defined like this:

```
{
     accessorKey: 'Severity',
     enableColumnFilter: true,
     enableSorting: true,
     filterFn: 'equals'
     header: 'Severity',
     sortDescFirst: true,
     sortingFn: (...): number => {...},
     cell: (props: any) => {...}
}
```

This is working fine with all the values passed to `state.ColumnFilters`, and the built-in filter functions `'equals'` and `'equalsString'`. If I use the function `'equalsStringSensitive'` I get the warning `Could not find a valid 'column.filterFn' for column with the ID: Severity`

With the filter functions `'equals'` and `'equalsString'` I meet the requirements, however, I would like to know if I might be missing something to make the `'equalsStringSensitive'` function to work that should be used with `'equals'` and `'equalsString'` as well.

Thanks!